# linux ls -l 5th column header size units?

Tags: terminal, ls

after I ran this command in my linux terminal,

```
ls -l
```

I get the information listed in long file format. Below is an example of my output:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 10  10011  10011       4096 Oct 14 18:51 hadoop-2.5.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root    148199785 Sep  5 19:43 hadoop-2.5.1.tar.gz
```

I understand what all of the columns are but I'm curious more specifically about what the 5th column (size of the file) is. I understand that it shows the size of the file, but in what units? Mb? k?

Obviously, it makes sense the scale the size of the units based on how large the files are in the directory. But how can we tell what the units are (if possible)? Take the example above, the hadoop-2.5.1.tar.gz file has a larger size value than the uncompressed version, which doesn't make much sense to me. Other than the fact that they're using different units..

The reason why I'm interested in knowing this is because I want to be able to see how much space I'm saving by processing text data files, compressing files, etc. I've tried searching the internet, I can't find a direct answer, even in the documentation. Please let me know what you all think. Thanks.

Comment: Ahhhh.....did you consult the man page for ls?

Comment: Yes... why don't you do a man ls and you'll see that -l only states "use a long listing format"..... doesn't include any info about the details of the column info..

Answer (score 2):

Source [What information is listed](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed)

> ‘-l’ ‘--format=long’ ‘--format=verbose’
>
> In addition to the name of each file, print the file type, file mode bits, number of hard links, owner name, group name, size, and
> timestamp (see Formatting file timestamps), normally the modification
> time. Print question marks for information that cannot be determined.
>
> **Normally the size is printed as a byte count without punctuation, but
> this can be overridden (see Block size).**
>
> For example, -h prints an
> abbreviated, human-readable count, and ‘--block-size="'1"’ prints a
> byte count with the thousands separator of the current locale.

Answer (score 1):

As DavidPostill said, the size is in bytes, unless you ask for a different format.

The reason why the size of the uncompressed version is smaller than the compressed one is that ls doesn't look at the contents of the directory, but only at the directory itself. The 4096 bytes you see here are used only for storing the list of files and directories in that directory, not their content.

If you wish to get the size of the directory with its contents, you need to use something like du.